# Laravel is a time between a start & end (Prevent double booking)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

I'm writing tests to make sure that a new reservation can not be double-booked over another another. I've read though countless other SO threads and now I'm more confused and not sure I'm doing anything right. I'm specifically using Laravel in my project as well as this example.

**Migration.php**

```
...
$table->date('date');       // 2020-01-01
$table->time('time_start'); // 15:00:00
$table->time('time_end');   // 17:00:00
...
```

I've worked with `dateTime` or `timezone`. I get into a trap of, "I don't *need* the date, just the time. I'm saving date somewhere else." I'll then find a thread that suggests saving as `timestamp` and compare the date there as well.

I have a reservation factory to generate (among other details) `date`, `time_start` and `time_end`:

**Factory.php**

```
'date' => date('Y-m-d'),
'time_start' => '15:00:00',
'time_end' => '17:00:00',
```

Most threads I've read suggest comparing using `strtotime`. Something like:

```
'time_start' => strtotime('15:00:00'),  // 1582210800
```

This makes sense. But then I read that saving as `dateTime` or `timezone` is better because of timezone.

In my controller I am checking for an existing reservation like this:

**Controller.php**

```
...
$existing = DB::table('reservations')
    ->where('asset_id', '=', $request->asset_id)
    ->whereDate('date', '=', $request->date)
    ->whereTime('time_start', '>=', $request->time_start)  // or use $request->strtotime('time_start')
    ->whereTime('time_end', '<=', $request->time_end)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where('status', '=', 'created')
            ->orWhere('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->orWhere('status', '=', 'completed');
    })
    ->get();

if ($existing->count() > 0) {
    // Not allowed
} else {
    // OK to proceed
}
...
```

Using [whereTime](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses) looks like exactly what I need:

```
->whereTime('created_at', '=', '11:20:45')
```

It looks like that would be saved as a `time` column. In my tests I am checking that I get a `400` back if it can't be created.

**Test.php**

```
...
$http->assertStatus(400)
    ->assertJsonStructure([
        'type', 'data' => [
            'reason'
        ]])
        ->assertJson([
            'type' => 'reservations',
            'data' => [
                'reason' => 'Asset is no longer available.',
            ],
        ]);
```

This works great. If I create a reservation that is `15:00:00` to `17:00:00` same date/asset etc. My test passes. I get the 400 error back exactly as I expect. However, if I pass `15:01:00` My test fails. Not surprised, but that tells me I am not handling the comparison correctly. It seems like I am right at the finish line, but then both shoes have come untied.

The UI will just be a drop down with human-readable times. I was planning on just saving the values as 24 hr time. For example, `15:00:00`. I'm not sure how else to do that...

I would be grateful for suggestions to better understand how:

- Best save the time(s) `time`, `timestamp`, `datetime`?
- Use `strtotime` (or not). If so, what's the ideal data type? `timestamp`, `datetime`?
- Use the appropriate error response; is 400 ideal?

Thank you so much for any thoughts.

**UPDATE**

Following @miken32 suggestion - I *did* have the relationships already set up that way so it made sense.

I am now saving `time_start` and `time_end` as a `dateTime` field in my migration.

**Controller.php**

```
$asset = Asset::find($request->asset_id);

$existing = $asset->reservations()
    ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $start_dt = new Carbon($request->time_start);
        $end_dt = new Carbon($request->time_end);

        $query->where('time_start', '>=', $start_dt)
            ->where('time_end', '<=', $end_dt);
        })
        ->whereIn('status', ['created', 'pending', 'completed'])
        ->get();

    if ($existing->count() > 0) {
        // Log::info('CANNOT MAKE RESERVATION FOR: ' . $request->first_name . ' ' . $request->last_name);
        return response()->json(['type' => 'reservations', 'data' => ['reason' => 'Asset is no longer available.']], 409);
    } else {
        $reservation = new Reservation();
        ...
        // Log::info('RESERVATION MADE FOR: ' . $reservation->first_name . ' ' . $reservation->last_name);
```

Users will only have the option to choose pre-determined time(s). Once a time slot has been reserved for any given asset, that block is un-available. I feel confident that I'm in essence making sure that someone can't (somehow) override the `POST` request with a different value.

Hopefully this will help someone else. If my implementation is off, please let me know so I can correct it for everyone else.

Comment: Well you probably don’t want to do `=` comparisons here, but `>=` / `<=`, don’t you think?

Comment: And you need to check for _two_ things - either start or end time falling _into_ any of the already existing booking intervals; or start being before and end after those of an existing booking (because you can’t make a new booking from 9am to 14am, if one from 10am to 11am already exists.)

Comment: 400 is not really an appropriate response here. Quote Wikipedia on HTTP status codes, “400 Bad Request - The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)” - none of that is actually the case here, assuming the parameters sent were actually valid dates and times. The mere fact that this booking request can not be satisfied due to an already existing booking, does not make this a client error that would justify a “bad request“ response.

Comment: @CBroe Yes I miss-typed my snippet. I have updated to correctly reflect what I have.

Comment: Like @CBroe said, this what your doing at the moment isn't going to be that great or even function like you are expecting it to function. There is a few more factors you should be taking into account. First of all you should have a buffer (this buffer is the x minutes u need in order to get a room cleaned and ready after someone elses reservation has ended). So you have to check wether the start time doesnt fall into a reservation and its buffer. You have to check wether an end time doesnt fall into for example a later booked reservation and its buffer. Then you also have to check wether the

Comment: - buffer from the reservation u are making fits into the block. Id recommend you to make an algorithm that calculates these available blocks of time and which will then translate into the frontend. making for example only times that are available clickable. or giving the user a recommended time frame based on the buffers, and how big the blocks of time are between certain reservations

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the feedback. @Tomm what you suggest is exactly what I (will) have. My UI has boxes a user can click. A box represents a duration (1 hr). Once a guest has clicked a box and completed the form, that box is disabled and cannot be selected again. Users can't manually enter a time. They can only select time(s) 8-9am, 10-11am etc. Since users can only choose time(s) I feel the risk of double-booking is low, but want to be more proactive in what I'm building. I can add more detail to my post if it helps. Trying to avoid being overwhelming or have ppl "do it for me".

Comment: I'd recommend storing start datetime and Length. End time becomes a computed or denormalized value. Works better with daylight saving. In FE you may of course present the end datetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be better off storing this information as two `DATETIME` columns. Advantages include being able to take advantage of Laravel's built-in casting to Carbon dates, and avoiding trouble with booking appointments over midnight.

Then, assuming `$request->time_start` and `$request->time_end` are full date/times, your query becomes something like this:

```php
$existing = DB::table('reservations')
    ->where('asset_id', $request->asset_id)
    ->where(
        fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('time_start', [$request->time_start, $request->time_end])
            ->orWhereBetween('time_end', [$request->time_start, $request->time_end])
            ->orWhere(
                fn ($q) => $q->where('time_start', '<', $request->time_start)
                    ->where('time_end', '>', $request->time_end);
            )
    )
    ->whereIn('status', ['created', 'pending', 'completed'])
    ->get();
```

You'd also add `time_start` and `time_end` to your model's `$dates` array to take advantage of [automatic casting](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

And speaking of models, if your relationships are set up correctly, this query could be like this, instead of using the `DB` facade:

```php
$asset = Asset::find($request->asset_id);
$existing = $asset
    ->reservations()
    ->where(
        fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('time_start', [$request->time_start, $request->time_end])
            ->orWhereBetween('time_end', [$request->time_start, $request->time_end])
            ->orWhere(
                fn ($q) => $q->where('time_start', '<', $request->time_start)
                    ->where('time_end', '>', $request->time_end)
            )
    )
    ->whereIn('status', ['created', 'pending', 'completed'])
    ->get();
```

It's no shorter, but IMO it makes it easier to see at a glance what's being searched for.

---

As for HTTP responses, it doesn't really matter what you use. It's all your code, so you know what to expect. But if you want to be pedantic (which I fully support) perhaps [409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) might suit your needs?

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH @miken32. I really appreciate the explanation. That really helped me think things out. I've updated my question based on your suggestions. Hopefully it's close.

Comment: No need to update the question if you’ve got an answer. The reason I used `whereBetween` was to catch overlaps. By using those two `where` methods, you’re only looking for conflicting entries that fall entirely within the user-selected range.

Comment: Well, this Gentle Reader does appreciate it when a question is clarified in the original post, as necessary.  But, don't *remove* the question because that's what a reader's going to look at first ... *"is this question the same as the one I have?"*  Plus, sometimes your original *uncertainty* matches the same perspective that the reader has at the time he stumbles-upon your thread, so don't take that away either.  (Add additional text to provide the clarification.)

Answer (score 0):

According to miken32, i've make some upgrades on the query, here it is:

I've added the following cases: start before and end in the middle of a reservation and start in the middle of a reservation and ends after.

*undestand $sr as the new space reservation*

```
$q->where(function ($q) use ($sr) {
            $q->where(function ($q) use ($sr) {
                $q->whereBetween('time_start', [$sr->time_start, $sr->time_end]);
                $q->orWhereBetween('time_end', [$sr->time_start, $sr->time_end]);
            });
            $q->orWhere(function ($q) use ($sr) {
                $q->where(function ($q) use ($sr) {
                    $q->where('time_start', '<', $sr->time_start);
                    $q->where('time_end', '>', $sr->time_end);
                });
                $q->orWhere(function ($q) use ($sr) {
                    $q->where('time_start', '<', $sr->time_start);
                    $q->whereBetween('time_end', [$sr->time_start, $sr->time_end]);
                });
                $q->orWhere(function ($q) use ($sr) {
                    $q->whereBetween('time_start', [$sr->time_start, $sr->time_end]);
                    $q->where('time_end', '<', $sr->time_end);
                });
            });
        });
```